# Does waitpid yield valid status information for a child process that has already exited?

Tags: c, fork, waitpid, posix-api

If I `fork` a child process, and the child process exits before the parent calls `waitpid`, then is the exit status information that is set by `waitpid` still valid? If so, when does it become not valid;  i.e., how do I ensure that I can call `waitpid` on the child pid and continue to get valid exit status information after an arbitrary amount of time, and how do I "clean up" (tell the OS that I am no longer interested in the exit status information for the finished child process)?

I was playing around with the following code, and it appears that the exit status information is valid for at least a few seconds after the child finishes, but I do not know for how long or how to inform the OS that I won't be calling `waitpid` again:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fork\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) { // code for child process
        _exit(17);
    }
    else { // code for parent
        sleep(3);

        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0); // call `waitpid` again just to see if the first call had an effect
        assert(WIFEXITED(status));
        assert(WEXITSTATUS(status) == 17);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `waitpid` will work after the child has exited. The OS will keep a child process' entry in the process table (including exit status) around until the parent calls `waitpid` (or another `wait`-family function) or until the parent exits (at which point the status is collected by the `init` process). This is what a "zombie" process is: a process that has exited by is still resident in the process table for exactly this purpose.

The process' entry in the table should go away after the first call to `waitpid`. I suspect the reason that in your example you seem to be able to call `waitpid` twice is simply because `waitpid` will not modify the `status` argument if `pid` no longer exists. So the first call should be working and filling in `status`, and the second call should be returning an error code and not changing `status`. You can verify this by inspecting the return values of the `waitpid` calls and/or using two different `status` variables.

Comment: Indeed, the second `waitpid` call did fail. I didn't think about that! Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

The OS keeps terminated process in a [zombie state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) until its parent (which might be the `init` if the original parent process terminated earlier) collects that exit status with `wait(2)` system call. So the answer is - the exit status of the process *does not become invalid*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid):

> A child that terminates, but has not
>   been waited for becomes a "zombie".
>   The kernel maintains a minimal set of
>   information about the zombie process
>   (PID, termination status, resource
>   usage information) in order to allow
>   the parent to later perform a wait to
>   obtain information about the child.